# Python3 "DeprecationWarning: ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 is deprecated sslcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)" error

Tags: python-3.x

Hi i downloaded a tool from github and when I try to run it, I get an alert like this;
linkfinder.py:133: DeprecationWarning: ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 is deprecated
sslcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

Tool : https://github.com/GerbenJavado/LinkFinder how to fix this error on python3?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1xAJ.png) --> code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKaeo.png) --> error

any idea?

Comment: Please mark as accepted if the solution answers your question.

Answer (score 10):

Please refer the [Python 3's SSL documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html).

> [`ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
>
> **Deprecated since version 3.6**: OpenSSL has deprecated all version specific protocols.

Recommendation:

Use either [`ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT) or [`ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER) as per your requirement.