# ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 is deprecated, So what should I do?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get an image.
Here is my code.

```
import io
import ssl
from urllib import request
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

item_image = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/180px-Cat03.jpg"
    
f = io.BytesIO(request.urlopen(item_image,context=context).read())
```

When I try this code, warning appiers

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7868\2896668910.py:4: DeprecationWarning: ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 is deprecated
  context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
```

I referred to this answer.
[Python3 "DeprecationWarning: ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 is deprecated sslcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306332/python3-deprecationwarning-ssl-protocol-tlsv1-2-is-deprecated-sslcontext-ssl)

So I tried to replace "ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2" to "ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT" or "ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER"

but both does not work.
I've read document but I can not understand.https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html

What shoud I do to clear this worning?

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly it is a matter of python configuration semantics (TLSv1.2 is still current, and supported by [wikipedea](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=upload.wikimedia.org&latest)), it's just the configuration approach has changed. Try:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext( ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT )
context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
context.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but still error occurs.

URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>

What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like the certs aren't available. Is it this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error